# Firefox 57 Quantum doesn't play remote audio over a remote desktop connection

Tags: firefox, audio, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

Why does Firefox 57 Quantum not play remote audio over a MSTSC remote desktop connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the FireFox 57.0 [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/57.0/releasenotes/) citing unresolved issues:

> Users running Firefox for Windows over a Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) may find that audio playback is disabled due to increased security restrictions. Learn how to mitigate this issue until it is corrected in an upcoming release

The notes include a link to a [support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/i-cant-play-audio-remote-desktop-connection) that includes instructions for implementing a workaround that will **reduce**(!) the sandbox security level:

1. In the address bar, type `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click **I accept the risk!** to continue to the about:config page.
2. Search for `security.sandbox.content.level` and set it to **2**.
3. Restart Firefox on the remote device.

Comment: More details on above change from [Mozilla Wiki - Security - Sandbox - Windows - Content](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox#Content) reveal that level 3 imposes restrictions and limits upon 2, such as the the [clipboard, handles, global atoms](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/6c2dbacbba1d58b8679cee700fd0a54189e0cf1b/security/sandbox/chromium/sandbox/win/src/job.cc#38) and extension functionality. Effectively disabling audio playback which uses handles and/or global atoms.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be resolved in Firefox 59 or higher.
It isn't mentioned any longer in the release notes under "unresolved issues".

However, if you're still having the same problem in Firefox 59 or higher, try closing Firefox and the RDP session and reopening both to reset the audio session settings. Worked for me, even without lowering the sandbox level.